# Monit fails to stop sidekiq 6

Tags: sidekiq, aws-opsworks, monit

I am upgrading to sidekiq6 we use monit. As sidekiq6 does not support PID(https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#running-your-own-process)file I am trying to stop using https://github.com/ajgon/opsworks_ruby/blob/master/templates/default/sidekiq.monitrc.erb.

Its not stopping on monit stop/restart etc .

```
[PST Mar  5 04:11:01] info     : 'sidekiq_cric-1' trying to restart
[PST Mar  5 04:11:01] info     : 'sidekiq_cric-1' stop: /bin/su
[PST Mar  5 04:12:31] error    : 'sidekiq_cric-1' failed to stop
[PST Mar  5 04:12:31] info     : 'sidekiq_cric-1' restart action done
```

If I run following on console it kills the job. 
 `stop  program = "/bin/su - deploy -c 'ps -ax | grep "bundle exec sidekiq" | grep sidekiq_1.yml| | grep -v grep | awk "{print \$1}" | xargs --no-run-if-empty pgrep -P | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill'" with timeout 90 seconds`

Please let me know what mistake I am doing here...

Answer (score 0):

Its working thanks  instead of grep "bundle exec sidekiq" I used grep sidekiq  without the double quote